# Is it possible to design a deep CNN model on a small size image dataset

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

I have started a project of classifying a dataset using deep learning. I have tried transfer learning on pretrained models. Now, I want to design a CNN model which can do this work of classification but everywhere it says it needs large data. My question is: Is it possible to design a deep CNN model on an image dataset of size less than 1000 images?

Comment: Transfer learning (pre-training on a large generic dataset) is the typical approach for these cases. Isn't transfer learning an acceptable approach in this case?

Comment: It is acceptable but we have to do something new to compare and show that it is competing with those results. So making a new model is the only possible way for me.

Comment: Then why not just training the same model from scratch on those 1000 images?

Comment: For example let's take GoogleNet. So many parameters but images are total 1000. Won't learning from scratch make it definitely overfit?

Comment: Of course, but isn't the purpose of the new model just gauge the performance of the model trained using transfer learning vs. not using it? Or do you just want to try other approaches that might be effective with a small data set?

Comment: First one is true. I can try. But focus is mainly on your second point. Yes, I want to try an effective approach for small data set.

Comment: Use shallow network otherwise it will overfit badly

Comment: @Aditya Can you tell me how shallow you mean?

Comment: Fist Cnn doesnt need more than 30 images in your validation dataset, and more than 100 images in your training[had been part of fast.ai and people had great results on very small datasets, exactly the nos i am quoting), by shallow i mean not more than 4 or 5 CNN blocks would be needed..if you want to see some arch's head over to kaggle's MNIST dataset for ann example

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the tip. May I ask as per you how will you divide the small data set(here in question 1000 total images) for training and validation?

Comment: 800 100 100 , training, validating, testing after stratified shuffling

Answer (score 1):

According to your description of the data, it is highly probable that training any neural network of reasonable size will overfit the training data.

One option is to apply any possible **regularization** approach; these come to mind:

- Use L1/L2 weight regularization.
- Reduce the number of parameters as much as you can (less layers, less number of filters).
- Use dropout.

Also, try any **data augmentation** trick: rotate images, mirror images, crop and scale images, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As [ncasas](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/14675/ncasas) answered, layer stacking and lesser number of filters do help. I didn't use dropout as I have very few parameters. Regularization is my next approach. I used **Batch Normalization** to generalize the model. It works very well.

Without Batch Normalization, model overfitted around 65% but using a single Batch Normalization generalized well upto 70%. Use it after **convolutional layer** for better results.